# Is it possible to have a cell of type object in a wijgrid?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, wijmo, wijgrid

I use a KnockOut observable array to populate a wijgrid. In the wijgrid, I'd like to use a JavaScript object as the value of some cells. Unfortunately, it seems as though wijmo converts objects to strings in it's own model.

Please have a [look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/muel/TM98D/2/). I'd like to display the vehicle owners name in table, but I need also to retain the id (and model data-structure).

**The KnockOut ViewModel**

```
var someData =[ { AssetCode: "Truck 5",
              Owner: {
                 id: 1,
                 name: 'Pete'},
              VIN: "T3SN2ADN",
              Odo: 232109,
              TimeStamp: "2012-07-21T09:13:12Z"},
            { AssetCode: "Car 8",
              Owner: {
                 id: 3,
                 name: 'Brian'},
              VIN: "COFAQ211",
              Odo: 433299,
              TimeStamp: "2012-07-17T15:34:54Z"}];

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.gridData = ko.observableArray(someData);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**The wijgrid**

```
<table id="t1" data-bind="wijgrid: {
    data: gridData,
    columns: [
    { headerText: 'Asset Code', dataKey: 'AssetCode', dataType: 'string'},
    { headerText: 'Owner name', dataKey: 'Owner'},         <!-- PROBLEM LINE -->
    { headerText: 'VIN', dataKey: 'VIN', dataType: 'string' },
    { headerText: 'Odometer', dateKey: 'Odo', dataType: 'number' },
    { headerText: 'Time', dataKey: 'TimeStamp', dataType: 'datetime', dataFormatString: timePattern }

]}"></table>
```

I've tried:

- the standard KnockOut approach: `{ headerText: 'Owner name', dataKey: 'Owner.name'}`
- creating a custom cellFormatter: `{ headerText: 'Owner name', dataKey: 'Owner', cellFormatter: MY_FORMATTER}`

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of to get this to work, but wijmo seems pretty rigid here....

Additionally, when I debug in Chrome, it appears as though wijmo has convert the object to a String in it's own model prior to any formatting. This isn't very useful..

**Edit** - We are using Wijmo 2.3.9. We've had performance problems with Wijmo 3.* thus far, so an upgrade isn't imminent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that you can get the cell value as an object using a `cellFormatter`... To get this to work, **do not** specify the `dataKey` attribute. Here is the amended code:

```
<table id="t1" data-bind="wijgrid: {
    data: gridData,
    columns: [
        { headerText: 'Asset Code', dataKey: 'AssetCode', dataType: 'string'},
        { headerText: 'Owner name', cellFormatter: MY_FORMATTER},         <!-- FIXED LINE -->
        { headerText: 'VIN', dataKey: 'VIN', dataType: 'string' },
        { headerText: 'Odometer', dateKey: 'Odo', dataType: 'number' },
        { headerText: 'Time', dataKey: 'TimeStamp', dataType: 'datetime', dataFormatString: timePattern }
]}"></table>
```

And the following JS:

```
var MY_FORMATTER = function(args) {
  if (args.row.data && args.row.dataRowIndex >= 0) {
    args.formattedValue = args.row.data.Owner.name;
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom value to any cell(or display the vehicle owners name in your case) by handling cellStyleFormatter like this:

```
cellStyleFormatter: function (args) {
//check for specific column and header row
if (args.column.headerText == "Owner name" && args.row.dataRowIndex >= 0) {
     //set the custom value to cell i.e. vehicle owner name
     args.$cell.text(args.row.data.Owner.name);
 }
}
```

For more information on CellStyleFormatter, you may refer : http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Grid#cellStyleFormatter

Comment: Unfortunately, the `cellStyleFormatter` suffers from the same problem as the `cellFormatter`. The value of `args.row.data.Owner` is: "[object Object]". Ie it's a String not an Owner object. This doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: I forgot to say thanks for the answer though. And if you've got any other ideas, I'm keen to try them out!